# How to make sense of modulo in c

Tags: c, modulo

i am not understanding this modulo in c languge.
For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int my_input[] = {23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18};
    int n, mod;
    int nbr_items = sizeof(my_input) / sizeof(my_input[0]);

    for (n = 0; n < nbr_items; n++)
    {
        mod = my_input[n] % 4;
        printf("%d modulo %d --> %d\n", my_input[n], 4, mod);
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
23 modulo 4 --> 3
22 modulo 4 --> 2
21 modulo 4 --> 1
20 modulo 4 --> 0
19 modulo 4 --> 3
18 modulo 4 --> 2
```

I would have expected a number that i can make sense of.
Essentially i am trying to test if a number is divisible by 4.

Comment: If a number is divisble by X, the modulo (which is the remainder of the division) is 0. In your case, 20 modulo 4 is 0, thus divisible by 4. What is it that you're not understanding?

Comment: thanks.  
Why 23 modulo 4 is 3 ? 
Why 22 modulo 4 is 2 ?  etc.

Comment: 23 = 4x5 + 3. So the result of 23 modulo 4 is 3. 22 = 4x5 + 2. So the result of 22 modulo 4 is 2. 19 = 4x4 + 3. So the result of 19 modulo 4 is 3. And so on. Did you read up on what a modulo, and what a remainder, is?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C. Google "how does modulo work" for dozens of millions of resources that'll explain every detail you want to know. It's a mathematical operator.

Comment: It should be noted that in c "%" is neither modulo nor remainder, due to the behaviour with negative numbers not matching the mathematically defined definitions. E.g. in c 5%(-3)=2 and (-5)%3=-2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The modulo operator in C will give the remainder that is left over when one number is divided by another. For example, 23 % 4 will result in 3 since 23 is not evenly divisible by 4, and a remainder of 3 is left over.

If you want to output whether or not a number is divisible by 4, you need to output something other than just the mod result. Essentially, if mod = 0 than you know that one number is divisible by another.

If you want to output whether or not the number is divisible by 4, I would suggest creating a new character that is set to "y" (yes) or "n" (no) depending on the result of the mod operation. Below is one possible implementation to generate a more meaningful output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int my_input[] = {23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18};
    int n, mod;
    char is_divisible;
    int nbr_items = sizeof(my_input) / sizeof(my_input[0]);

    for (n = 0; n < nbr_items; n++)
    {
        mod = my_input[n] % 4;
        is_divisible = (mod == 0) ? 'y' : 'n';
        printf("%d modulo %d --> %c\n", my_input[n], 4, is_divisible);
    }
}
```

This will give the following:

```
23 modulo 4 --> n
22 modulo 4 --> n
21 modulo 4 --> n
20 modulo 4 --> y
19 modulo 4 --> n
18 modulo 4 --> n
```

Comment: I think you mean you ternary operation to be `is_divisible = mod == 0 ? 'y' : 'n'`?

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure we know the basic division equation from high school math

dividend = divisor*quotient + remainder

Now: 
1. The "/" operator gives us the quotient. 
2. The "%" operator gives us the remainder

example:

```
    say a = 23, b = 4
    a / b = 23 / 4 = 5
    a % b = 23 % 4 = 3

    23 = 4*5 + 3
```

Here 4 is the quotient and 3 is the remainder.

If a number is perfectly divisible by a divisor, then remainder is zero.

So:

```
    20/4 = 5 (quotient)
    20%4 = 0 (remainder)
```

To test if a no if divisible by 4, the check should be something like **if (num % 4 == 0)**. 
Hope this helps!