# i want to add a constant to an array of numbers but differently in C

Tags: c

for example i have an array with elements
`0 1 2 3 4 5 6`
i want to add say 3 to all the elements and want this output:
`3 4 5 6 0 1 2` after the addition the numbers should not exceed the largest element, but start from the smallest one.
Hard to explain.
Is there some way of doing this in c? (not c++)

Comment: What's the result for the list `1 2 3`?

Comment: What you are trying to do is *modulo arithmetic*, and the operator `%`  gives you the remainder (or modulo) of an integer. You simply add the increment to each array element and then store `elem%7`.

Comment: @bereal adding 3 to your list it remains same

Comment: I think you need to investigate the [modulo operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43302709/10871073).

Comment: Iterate through the array once to find the maximum element, let's call that `m`. Then iterate through the array again, do the addition for each element and assign the result modulo `m + 1` back.

Comment: @Arkku Ah yes, if the modulo is the largest element +1 then one has to find it first.

Comment: @Arkku your method worked.  can you write the same thing as an answer, i would mark that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing seems to be addition modulo the maximum element + 1, i.e., a sum greater than the maximum element wraps around.

1. Find the maximum element, let's call it `max`, by iterating over the array.
2. Iterate over the array again, and for each element do the addition modulo `max + 1`, i.e., conceptually `arr[i] = (arr[i] + n) % (max + 1)`.

(If it was intended that the wrap-around is not to zero but to the minimum element, then also find the smallest value in step 1 and do `arr[i] = ((arr[i] - min + n) % ((max - min) + 1)) + min` in step 2.)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly you need something like the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t max_element( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t max = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[max] < a[i] ) max = i;
    }

    return max;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    int value = 0;

    printf( "Enter a value to add to elements of the array: " );
    scanf( "%d", &value );

    size_t max = max_element( a, N );

    int upper_value = a[max] + 1;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = ( a[i] + value ) % upper_value;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a value to add to elements of the array: 3
3 4 5 6 0 1 2
```