# What means rand() % range + lower?

Tags: c

Im learning C right now and I don't understand what the `rand() % range + lower` in this line of code means.

```
printf("I will generate 10 random numbers between %d and %d . . .\n", lower, upper);

int range = upper - lower+1;                        
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {                      
    int number = rand() % range + lower;            
    printf("%d\t", number);
```

Comment: Do you know what the `%` operator is?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43302709/how-to-make-sense-of-modulo-in-c) post explains what the `%` operator does. The use of modulus (`%`) in combination with the `+` achieves what's in the `printf` statement.

Comment: The C library function int rand(void) returns a pseudo-random number in the range of 0 to RAND_MAX.

Comment: The rand () function will return you a random number. This number can be very large or small in digits. % This operator performs the mod operation. (rand () % range) returns the remainder of the division of the this random number by range. 
So you get a random number between 0 and (range-1), and anything you add to that number gives you the lower bound.

Comment: Please explain what puzzles you, because I get the impression that with "will generate ... random numbers between ... lower and upper" the question contains the answer.

Comment: Suppose you want a random number in the range `lower=2`, `upper=5` so you want to get 2, 3, 4 or 5. This is four possibilities, which you get from `upper - lower + 1`  = `4`. Next, `rand() % 4` gives a number in the range 0..3  and finally you add that to `lower` to give one of the four possibilities.

Comment: Thanks you everybody for your help!
@WeatherVane fixed the problem for me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor man's linear random generator.

It is indeed random because is is fed from `rand()` which returns an random integer, and by construction the value is >= lower and <= upper.

But it is still a poor man's tool because the values in the [lower, upper] interval may have different probabilities.

Long story made short, it can be used if you just need some random values but should not be if you need a cryptographic secure random source.

Comment: It is just an excercise from my professor, dealing with random numbers.
But I dont get the idea behind **range +lower**.

Comment: It isn't `range + lower`. It is `(rand() % range) + lower`.

Answer (score 0):

Please read abut % operator. It is modulo division.
Modulo division is good tool to uniform mapping biggest range to shortest range (in your case *rand() % range*). You just need add start of range to shift all values to correct positions.
Code *rand() % range + lower* is standard C idiom to get random numbers from A,B range. You can find more idioms, for example for floating-points numbers with (A,B) range or <A,B> range.

Comment: And from OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355974/what-means-rand-range-lower#comment115544364_65356196) "what is `range + lower`?" note that the `%` operator has higher precedence than the `+` operator.