# C Program with while loop

Tags: c, while-loop

So, this program is displaying the sum of even numbers and the sum of odd numbers. When i type an odd number divisible by 3 the program should stop, but it isnt stopping. What do i need to write in `while (here)` to make it work? I need to make it with While, not other loop. This is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()

{
    int n=0, sumpr=0, sumim=0;
    
    printf ("Introduceti valori lui n:");
    
    while ( ) 
    
    {
        scanf ("%i", &n); 
        if (n%2==0) sumpr+=n ; 
        else sumim+=n;
    };
    
    printf ("Suma nr. pare=%i\n", sumpr);
    printf ("Suma nr. impare=%i", sumim);
}
```

Comment: familiar with [modular division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43302709/how-to-make-sense-of-modulo-in-c)? You should be, it's used in your loop body.

Comment: You are reading in values and only check them afterwards, so I'd rather prefer a `do while` loop. In the end both loops work – normal while loop *provided* you initialise `n` to a value *not* dividable by 3! Whichever you chose the loop then checks if *not* being dividable by 3 to continue. How did you check for being even? Being dividable by 2, so you only need to exchange the value (and the comparison operator)...

Comment: since you are reading the input within the while loop, better option would be to use a `do while` loop. Otherwise you can use a `while(true)` loop and break out of the loop on the required condition: `if (n%3 == 0) break;`

Comment: `while( 1 == scanf("%i", &n) && ! ( n % 2 == 1 && n % 3 == 0) )`

Comment: So how are you going to get out of the while loop? You have no break or test condition.

Answer (score -1):

```
while ( ) 
    
    {
        scanf ("%i", &n); 
        if (n%2==0) sumpr+=n ; 
        else sumim+=n;
        break;
    };
```

Comment: 1. Not properly formatted. 2. Breaking unconditionally, which is not what was asked for!